# backslash seach not working in chinese character in marklogic

Tags: xpath, marklogic, flwor

I am using following `cts query` for the search in MarkLogic

```
cts:element-word-query(xs:QName('c:l10n'),'\*\漢\*',('wildcarded','case-insensitive','whitespace-sensitive'))
```

It is not giving any result although there exists some data in the database with "\漢" words.

already tried:
It is working fine with English characters like `\r`,`\n` or `/r`,`/n`.
also, it gives me perfect result if I use only `\` or `漢`. but always show 0 results whenever I use `\` with any Chinese character.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible that there is a tokenization bug here, but it is hard to tell.

What you (should) have here is a phrase query for "\" (wildcard-word) "\" "漢" "\" and (wildcard-word) in that order. It is punctuation sensitive. Do you have an example of some content you think should match?

What does the query plan show you?  What are your index settings?